# adding arraylist to hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap, hashtable

I need to put array of elements in a loop with a particular key....suppose if I am getting key 1 then its data is to be appended to that key index and so on..problem I am facing is when I put on key 2 after 1 and then when again come back on 1 to put more data, it replaces the old data and so on.

```
        arraylist1.add(dataPacket.coordinate);


        if (map1.containsKey(dataPacket.transmitterID)) {
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Coordinate>> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
                int key = entry.getKey();
                if(key==dataPacket.transmitterID) {
                    List<Coordinate> values = entry.getValue();
                    values.add(dataPacket.coordinate);
                    map1.put(dataPacket.transmitterID, values);
                }
            }
        } else {
            map1.put(dataPacket.transmitterID, arraylist1);
        }
        arraylist1.clear();
```

Comment: is that your whole code that you are using for this?

Comment: yes datapacket.transmitter id is an integer which i am putting as key and datapacket.coordiantes are lat,lng which i am saving in arraylist

Comment: HashMap doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: why don't you put it in another hash map of same type

Comment: i dnt want duplicate keys, i want then when data for key1  comes it should be appended at next index to previous data on 1 but right now it is replacing the data

Comment: can you post your datapacket class here?

Comment: datapackets is a complete transmitter class getting data from bluetooth connection, you can simply consider  as dummy integer values in key and values if you can help

Comment: can you post the complete code where you are using this piece of code? there is no error in this code . It might be somewhere else